# Disable streamlit buttons after user click

Tags: css, openai-api, streamlit

I have the following code that creates a streamlit web app that uses gpt. Each user question is followed by a bot response and each of the bot response is followed by two buttons. These buttons are used to implement a specific business logic.
However, the idea is that the user, after the bot response, should be able to click on either of the two buttons, BUT, after the execution of the logic for the specific clicked button, all the two buttons shouold be disabled (in order to prevent the user from clicking them again). This process happens iteratively.
The issues I have are two:

1. Im not able to disable all the two buttons
2. If I disable one of them, in the next iteration the button would result disabled by default (not enabling the user to click).

Here is the code:

```
import os
import tempfile
import streamlit as st
from pdfquery import PDFQuery



st.set_page_config(page_title="Scegli Fiat Panda", page_icon="./img/xxxx.jpg")

with open("./style/style.css") as f:
    st.markdown(f'<style>{f.read()}</style>', unsafe_allow_html=True)

welcome_message = "xxxxxxx"
second_welcome_msg = "xxxxx"


# Definisci il percorso del file direttamente
file_to_ingest = "./data/xxx.pdf"


# Imposta la chiave API GPT
OPENAI_API_KEY = "xxxxx"

def disable():
    st.session_state.disabled = True


def display_messages():
    for i, (msg, is_user) in enumerate(st.session_state["messages"]):
        if is_user:
            with st.chat_message("user"):
                st.markdown(msg)
        else:
            with st.chat_message("assistant"):
                st.markdown(msg)
                if welcome_message in msg:
                    st.image("./img/panda.jpeg", width = 600)

                # Add buttons after each bot response with unique keys
                columns = st.columns([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
                with columns[0]:
                    # Initialize disabled for form_submit_button to False
                    if "disabled" not in st.session_state:
                        st.session_state.disabled = False
                    continue_chat_button = st.button(f"Continua a fare domande su Panda {i}", on_click=disable, disabled=st.session_state.disabled)
                with columns[3]:
                    request_price_button = st.button(f"Richiedi un preventivo gratuito {i}", key = f"b {i}")


                # Check button clicks
                if continue_chat_button:
                    request_price_button = st.button(f"Richiedi un preventivo gratuito {i}", on_click=disable, disabled=st.session_state.disabled)
                    st.session_state["user_input_disabled"] = False  # Re-enable user input
                    st.session_state["user_input"] = ""
                    #st.session_state["show_buttons"] = False  # Hide buttons
                    st.empty()


                if not continue_chat_button and not request_price_button:
                    st.session_state["user_input_disabled"] = True  # SE NON VIENE CLICCATO CONTNIUE TO CHAT BUTTON ALLORA USER INPUT DISABLED

                elif request_price_button:
                    st.session_state["user_input_disabled"] = True  # Disable further user input
                    st.session_state["show_buttons"] = False  # Hide buttons
                    st.empty()

                    # Display form for user to input first name, last name, and email
                    with st.form("price_request_form"):
                        st.write("Inserisci le seguenti informazioni:")
                        first_name = st.text_input("Nome", key="first_name")
                        last_name = st.text_input("Cognome", key="last_name")
                        email = st.text_input("Email", key="email")

                        # Every form must have a submit button.
                        submitted = st.form_submit_button("Invia")

                        if submitted:
                            # Clear the form inputs
                            st.session_state["first_name"] = ""
                            st.session_state["last_name"] = ""
                            st.session_state["email"] = ""
                            
                            # Clear the page and display the thank you message
                            st.empty()
                            st.write("Grazie per aver richiesto un preventivo gratuito")


    st.session_state["thinking_spinner"] = st.empty()

def process_input():
    if st.session_state["user_input"] and len(st.session_state["user_input"].strip()) > 0:
        user_text = st.session_state["user_input"].strip()
        with st.session_state["thinking_spinner"], st.spinner(f"Calcolando..."):
            query_text = st.session_state["pdfquery"].ask(user_text)

        st.session_state["messages"].append((user_text, True))
        st.session_state["messages"].append((query_text, False))

        # Clear user input after processing
        st.session_state["user_input"] = ""

def read_and_save_file(file_to_ingest):
    st.session_state["pdfquery"].forget()
    st.session_state["user_input"] = ""
    
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as tf:
        with open(file_to_ingest, 'rb') as file:
            tf.write(file.read())
        file_path = tf.name

    st.session_state["pdfquery"].ingest(file_path)
    os.remove(file_path)

    if st.session_state["show_welcome_message"]:
        st.session_state["messages"].append((welcome_message, False))
        st.session_state["show_welcome_message"] = False

def is_openai_api_key_set() -> bool:
    return len(OPENAI_API_KEY) > 0


def main():

    
    if len(st.session_state) == 0:
        st.session_state["messages"] = []
        st.session_state["pdfquery"] = PDFQuery(OPENAI_API_KEY)
        st.session_state["show_welcome_message"] = True
        st.session_state["user_input_disabled"] = True  # Initial state: user input is disabled
        st.session_state["show_buttons"] = True  # Initial state: show buttons

    

    read_and_save_file(file_to_ingest)

    st.session_state["ingestion_spinner"] = st.empty()


    if st.session_state["messages"]:
        display_messages()


        # Conditionally display the text input based on user_input_disabled
        if not st.session_state["user_input_disabled"]:
            user_input = st.text_input('Scrivi qualcosa qui ', key="user_input", disabled=not is_openai_api_key_set(),
                                       on_change=process_input, placeholder="Messaggio...")
            


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Can you help me fix this? I've tried everything that came in mind. Thanks

I tried to use streamlit sessions, to access css class ids for each button and much more, but was not able to solve the issue.